# For Loop overwrites previous iteration

Tags: python, file, for-loop, path

I try to extract the second frame of every video in a video list and save every frame as a single individual image file.

```
frame_no = 2

dir_list = ['a', 'b']

dir_lust_full = ['C:/User/video/a.mp4','c:/User/video/b.mp4']

# Loop currently overwrites each iteration. 
for i in list(dir_list_full): 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i) 
    cap.set(1,frame_no)  
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
    for x in dir_list:
        isWritten = cv2.imwrite('C:/User/Frames/frame_'+ x +'.png', frame) 
        

if isWritten:
    print('Frames are successfully saved as individual files.')
```

However, the loop saves the exact frame it currently iterates to every image file it created. Ultimately, every file has the same frame (from the last video) as the loop finishes.

Can someone help me what I do wrong here? Thanks! =)

Comment: There is no bug here, but that second loop is not doing what you expect it do. Put some print()'s in there or step through it to see what happens. Also: I think you're supposed to ````.release()```` a VideoCapture object before opening it again ? Has nothing to do with the behaviour here, though.

Comment: I also think the second loop is the problem here. It may be unnecessary if there is a way to only label each new image file that is being saved according to the element in dir_list? Hence, in ``` isWritten = cv2.imwrite('C:/User/Frames/frame_'+ x +'.png', frame) ``, a different method for ' + x + ' is necessary?

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. please learn to debug. the MRE article links to a "how to debug" article.

Comment: Welcome to SO, by the way! There's a bit of learning curve to learning how to ask good, on-topic questions, but if you stick with it and take the time to read through relevant help center pages, you'll get the hang of it! Debugging is also a great skill to learn, and can be a more efficient way to solve certain problems without having to ask here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want to do something like that:

```
frame_no = 2
dir_list_source = ["C:/User/video/a.mp4", "c:/User/video/b.mp4"]
dir_list_target = ["a", "b"]

for i in range(len(dir_list_source)): 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(dir_list_source[i])

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Cannot open {dir_list_source[i]}")
        exit()

    cap.set(1, frame_no)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print(f"Error reading frame from {dir_list_source[i]}")
        exit()

    cv2.imwrite(f"C:/User/Frames/frame_{dir_list_target[i]}.png", frame)
    cap.release()

print("Frames successfully saved as individual files.")
```